# habilitar opção no select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tenho o seguinte select:

```
    <select id="selectChannel" class="form-control form-control-sm custom-select">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled">Selecione o canal</option>
        <option value="1" disabled="disabled">Canal 1</option>
        <option value="2">Canal 2</option>
        <option value="3">Canal 3</option>
        <option value="4">Canal 4</option>
    </select>
```

---

toda vez que uma pewssoa adiciona algum dos canais, eu desabilito para que não seja possivel adicionar o mesmo canal mais de uma vez. Quando clicado em adicionar, só executo o seguinte comando para desabilitar

```
$("#selectChannel option:selected").attr('disabled','disabled')
```

---

O que preciso, é quando o usuario deletar um canal, que a opção esteja disponivel novamente.
Tenho a informação de qual canal está sendo deletado, mas como faço para habilitar a opção no select?

Comment: Como você faz para "deletar o canal" ? O seu código só mostra o `select` dos canais e o método de desabilitar o mesmo.. Você também não explicou porque realmente você precisa deletar o canal e etc, tente deixar sua questão mais clara possível.

Comment: "_Tenho a informação de qual canal está sendo deletado_"... qual seria essa informação? O value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se tens o `value` podes usar um seletor que o encontre e remover o atributo com [`removeAttr`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/). Um seletor possível seria `option[value="2"]`...

Por exemplo:

```
$('#selectChannel option[value="2"]').removeAttr('disabled')
```

Comment: isso resolveu. Obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

Este exemplo pode te ajudar:

```js
$('[data-canal]').click(function() 
{

const el = $(this);

$(`#selectChannel option[value="${el.data('canal')}"]`).prop('disabled', false);

el.remove();

});
```

```css
p {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <select id="selectChannel" class="form-control form-control-sm custom-select">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled">Selecione o canal</option>
        <option value="1" disabled="disabled">Canal 1</option>
        <option value="2" disabled>Canal 2</option>
        <option value="3" disabled>Canal 3</option>
        <option value="4" disabled>Canal 4</option>
</select>

<div>
<p data-canal="1">deletar Canal 1</p>
<p data-canal="2">deletar Canal 2</p>
<p data-canal="3">deletar Canal 3</p>
<p data-canal="4">deletar Canal 4</p>
</div>
```